# how to set UTC timezone easily

Tags: php, html, css

I have got a signup form where I am trying to get the user to select their country and at the same time, inputting the time that they have enrolled or signed up but I can't get it to display the time accurately unless I use `date_default_timezone_set` for each state and there are a lot of timezone to use.

I am just wondering, what is the most effective way to do this and I have seen on hotmail.com that they also ask for UTC timezone, is this a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately you don't need to reinvent the wheel. Others have done the legwork and posted their solution on the web.

Since you are already asking for a country you can probably piggyback off this code: [GitHub: maxmind/geoip-api-php](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/src/timezone.php)

In a lot of cases the country will only have one timezone. In the cases where there are more than one you could trigger a select field with the timezones available for that country. This solution isn't ready to go out-of-the-box but it shouldn't take too much work to get it running.

There might be a more complete code out there that's ready to use too, you'll just have to do a little digging around.

Comment: I haven't used function before but would I just call the following function as in echo get_time_zone();

Comment: I tried to put that code in a file called timezone2.php and include it in timezone.php, then I used get_time_zone(); and it asked me to pass in some variables, so I passed $country and $region but it doesn't recognise it

Comment: Does your form use the ISO alpha-2 country codes? How are you setting the region? CA, NZ, and US use a two character code for province, region, and state respectively. Some other countries use numeric codes for regional subdivisions.

Comment: I just use a select tag with all the countries as a string variable

Comment: That is precisely why the function is not returning anything. If you look at the switch statements in that API you will see that they are using the 2-letter country code to determine which timezone(s) to return. If you don't send the right arguments to the function it won't return the right result.